# Web Forms and Bootstrap Form Issue

Tags: css, asp.net, forms, webforms

I am using a stripped down version of Admin LTE Bootstrap Theme on a ASP.NET Web Forms Project. In a web forms project you can only use 1 form tag per page.

The form tag needs to go around all Top (Nav) and Bottom (Side Bar Left & Main, the Main Content). Both sections have elements that require the form for rendering. Here is a basic layout of the page and divs (I named some of them so you can see the relation to the tags I wrote out below.

```
<Body>
<Form>
<header>   
    <Nav Bar>   
        <Nav Bar -Right>
    </Nav Bar>
</header>
<Wrapper>
    <Side Bar -Left>
    <Main Content -Right>
</Wrapper>
</Form>
</Body>
```

[image]

When I put the form tag around all major divs I get a style or push from around the edge of the entire screen and it pushes my logo (png or jpg) out of the nav down. Here is what that looks like.

[image]

So it must be when I place that form tag between the body and the header, I have no where else to place it. The end of the form tag is placed between the body end tag and the wrapper end tag. That is the only place it can go. The form when wrapped around bootstrap pushes everything down at the nav.

The frame work I am using is right out of the box at this link:

[enter link description here](http://bootstrapstage.com/admin-lte/)

ANy idea of how to get the form tag from screwing up my header tag contents and pushing them down. I have tried using developer tools but I have so many styles to sort through. Is it as simple as killing the formatting on the form tag in css. I tried that and it dint help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would work but you can try it. Add a class to your form called test-form then add this css to the page

```
.test-form {
     position: fixed;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     z-index: 0;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 0;
}
```

**UPDATE**: so here is the solution

"I found that the error is caused because the theme uses the following css for the header and side bar: body > .header so by removing the > from any of the AdminLTE header.less file should work"

Comment: Thanks Im trying it out.

Comment: I'm sorry to say it didn't work. I even tried putting it in my override page, I put it in the LTEAdmin.css, I tried inlining it. adding !important lol

Comment: Another solution would be to use jQuery or javascript to serialize your form.

Comment: I found that the error is caused because the theme uses the following css for the header and side bar: body > .header so by removing the > from any of the AdminLTE header.less file should work

Comment: Let me make those changes.

Comment: That worked. I had to change it in header.less and adminLTE.less good to go!