# My Form is adding padding to my page

Tags: css, forms, tags, user-agent

I have a form wrapped around the bootstrap wrapper and it's causing my logo to push the navigation underneath itself. Very odd.

[image]

Any idea how to override that style? I think it's because it's block? I tried using:

```
<form id="ScriptManager" runat="server"  style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
```

that's not affecting it all.

The code on my page is the same as on the admin LTE index page below. I have moved myform to encompass all divs on the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head runat="server">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Site ~ Project Tracking Dashboard</title>
        <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no' name='viewport'>
        <!-- bootstrap 3.0.2 -->
        <link href="../../dash_css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!-- font Awesome -->
        <link href="../../dash_css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!-- Ionicons -->
        <link href="../../dash_css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!-- Theme style -->
        <link href="../../dash_css/AdminLTE.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!-- jQUI CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

    </head>
    <body class="skin-blue">
        <!-- header logo: style can be found in header.less -->
        <!-- search form -->
        <form id="ScriptManager" runat="server"  style="margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important;">
        <header class="header">
            <a href="../../index.html" class="logo">
                <img src="/Images/LargeDark.svg" class="icon" width="130" alt="ArchiTrack Logo" />
            </a>
            <!-- Header Navbar: style can be found in header.less -->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
                <!-- Sidebar toggle button-->
                <a href="#" class="navbar-btn sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" role="button">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </a>
                <div class="navbar-right">
                    ....NAV BAR RIGHT
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <div class="wrapper row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
            <!-- Left side column. contains the logo and sidebar -->
            <aside class="left-side sidebar-offcanvas">                
                <!-- sidebar: style can be found in sidebar.less -->
                <section class="sidebar">
                    <!-- Sidebar user panel -->
                    ....USER PANEL
                </section>
                <!-- /.sidebar -->
            </aside>

            <!-- Right side column. Contains the navbar and content of the page -->
            <aside class="right-side">                
                <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
                <section class="content-header">
                    <h1>Dashboard<small> ~Site Name</small></h1>
                    <ol class="breadcrumb">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard</a></li>
<%--                        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>--%>
                        <li><a href="#">Tasks</a></li>
                        <li class="active">Incomplete</li>
<%--                        <li class="active">Complete</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Timesheets</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Mailbox</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Preferences</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Calendar</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Comments</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">User Directory</a></li>
                        <li class="active">Blank page</li>--%>
                    </ol>
                </section>

                <!-- Main content -->
                <section class="content">

                    ....CONTENT

                </section><!-- /.content -->

            </aside><!-- /.right-side -->

        </div><!-- ./wrapper -->

        </form>
        <!-- jQuery 2.0.2 -->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <script src="../../dash_js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!-- AdminLTE App -->
        <script src="../../dash_js/AdminLTE/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes 
        <script src="js/AdminLTE/demo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->

        <!-- jQuery UI -->
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $(".dPicker").datepicker();
            });
      </script>
      <!-- jQuery UI -->

    </body>
</html
```

Comment: Need moar code. You gave us bare minimum here.

Comment: I added the source code, I took out some navigation and content but left all the main divs. Admin LTE is the name of the bootstrap theme, i have used it before on a non .NET site and had no problems. But for .NET i need to move the tag to wrap all elements (divs) on the page.

Comment: What browser is this in?

Comment: Im getting this in all browsers. IE, Chrome & Opera

Comment: Probably a margin to on an element that's overflowing out of the container

Comment: We need to see the AdminLTE.css. I think without that, we're just throwing out guesses at the moment.

Comment: It's 3405 lines long. THat's why I linked to the admin theme. I can't post that here can i?

Comment: @EricB hey where you able to solve this.i have the same issue .Please help

Comment: Yes, Let me get the solution for you. It's in another thread.

Comment: The answer is at the bottom of this thread. If you find it useful, please upvote the question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24559525/web-forms-and-bootstrap-form-issue

Comment: maybe add this css: `margin:0; padding:0;`

Comment: @www139, the question was actually answered by the author of the bootstrap theme. The comment just above yours has the answer. Thanks for commenting though, I always appreciate anyone taking the time to answer!